# PySpark - optimize number of partitions after parquet read

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, partitioning, parquet

In a parquet data lake partitioned by `year` and `month`, with `spark.default.parallelism` set to i.e. `4`, lets say I want to create a DataFrame comprised of months 11~12 from 2017, and months 1~3 from 2018 of two sources `A` and `B`.

```
df = spark.read.parquet(
    "A.parquet/_YEAR={2017}/_MONTH={11,12}",
    "A.parquet/_YEAR={2018}/_MONTH={1,2,3}",
    "B.parquet/_YEAR={2017}/_MONTH={11,12}",
    "B.parquet/_YEAR={2018}/_MONTH={1,2,3}",
)
```

If I get the number of partitions, Spark used `spark.default.parallelism` as default:

```
df.rdd.getNumPartitions()
Out[4]: 4
```

Taking into account that after creating `df` I need to perform `join` and `groupBy` operations over each period, and that data is more or less evenly distributed over each one (around 10 million rows per period):

**Question**

- Will a repartition improve the performance of my subsequent operations?
- If so, if I have 10 different periods (5 per year in both A and B), should I repartition by the number of periods and explicitly reference the columns to repartition (`df.repartition(10,'_MONTH','_YEAR')`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will a repartition improve the performance of my subsequent operations?

Typically it won't. The only reason to preemptively repartition data is to avoid further shuffling when the same `Dataset` is used for multiple joins, based on the same condition

> If so, if I have 10 different periods (5 per year in both A and B), should I repartition by the number of periods and explicitly reference the columns to repartition (df.repartition(10,'_MONTH','_YEAR'))?

Let's go step-by-step:

- > should I repartition by the number of periods

  Practitioners don't guarantee 1:1 relationship between levels and partitions, so the only thing to remember is, that you cannot have more non-empty partitions than unique keys, so using significantly larger value doesn't make sense.
- > and explicitly reference the columns to repartition

  If you `repartition` and subsequently `join` or `groupBy` using the same set of columns for both parts is the only sensible solution.

**Summary**

`repartitoning` before join makes sense in two scenarios:

- In case of multiple subsequent `joins`

  ```
  df_ = df.repartition(10, "foo", "bar")
  df_.join(df1, ["foo", "bar"])
  ...
  df_.join(df2, ["foo", "bar"])
  ```
- With single join when desired number of the *output* partitions is different than `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` (and there is no broadcast join)

  ```
  spark.conf.get("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions")
  # 200
  spark.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", -1)

  df1_ = df1.repartition(11, "foo", "bar")
  df2_ = df2.repartition(11, "foo", "bar")

  df1_.join(df2_, ["foo", "bar"]).rdd.getNumPartitions()
  # 11

  df1.join(df2, ["foo", "bar"]).rdd.getNumPartitions()
  # 200
  ```

  which might be preferable over:

  ```
  spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 11)
  df1.join(df2, ["foo", "bar"]).rdd.getNumPartitions()
  spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 200)
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. Perfectly explained!